# jQuery UI (run when visible on screen)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Im trying to make my jQuery only trigger when it is seen on the screen. It triggers some bars to bounce but the user needs to scroll through content before it is visible.

Other then delaying its timing (which could be hit and miss for some users) how can i make this code trigger when it becomes visible on screen?

```
<script>
$(function() {
$(".meter .bar").hide().show('bounce', { times:4, direction: 'right' }, 1780);                    
});
</script>
```

is this correct?

Im trying to make my jQuery only trigger when it is seen on the screen. It triggers some bars to bounce but the user needs to scroll through content before it is visible.

Other then delaying its timing (which could be hit and miss for some users) how can i make this code trigger when it becomes visible on screen?

```
<script>
$(function() {
$(".meter .bar").hide().show('bounce', { times:4, direction: 'right' }, 1780);                    
});
</script>
```

is this correct?

```
<script>
$('.meter .bar:visible').livequery(function () {
$(".meter .bar").hide().show('bounce', { times:4, direction: 'right' }, 1780);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using http://plugins.jquery.com/livequery/ with something like:
    var isExecuting = false;

```
$('.meter .bar:visible').livequery(function () {
    if (!isExecuting) {
      isExecuting = true;
      // some stuff
      $(".meter .bar").hide().show('bounce', { times:4, direction: 'right' }, 1780)
                      .completed(function() { isExecuting = false; };
    }
});
```

This will cause the some stuff to be executed each time it become visible.

Comment: can you check the revised question. my js isn't great

Comment: i added a lot of br's to trigger the scroll bar. this is the [link](http://music.insanitypop.com/bars.html)

Comment: You need to include the livequery plugin to use it. I had an ancient link in the post, here's a new one: http://plugins.jquery.com/livequery/

Comment: ah yes its working now, only problem is it is blinking when it becomes visible on the screen for about 2 seconds, then it loads

Comment: You should put a check in to see if it's executing right now before it beginning to run. I think it might trigger as every new portion of the thing is exposed. I'll update my answer.